# What is the Expiry date of CloudWatch Logs Agent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there any expiry date of log files, generated by EC2 instance in CloudWatch logs using CloudWatch Logs Agent ?

Comment: Your question is too vague, can you explain more what do you want to know? If you can have an example that's better

Comment: Sure Sir,   I have EC2 Instance , and Install CloudWatch Agent and start AWSlogs service. So is it any expiry date of CloudWatch logs ?\

Answer (score 2):

> By default, log data is stored indefinitely. However, you can
>   configure how long you want to store log data in a log group. Any data
>   older than the current retention setting is automatically deleted. You
>   can change the log retention for each log group at any time.

For more information:
[Changing Log Retention](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/SettingLogRetention.html)